# Check if file exists in ksh

Tags: ksh

I wonder why the below tiny script is now working.
I created dfFile under /data directory but script does not print the expressions in if statement.

```
#!/bin/ksh
DATAFILE="/data/dfFile"
echo $DATAFILE
#df -h>/data/dfFile
  if [[ -e DATAFILE ]]
  then
    echo "sa"
    echo $DATAFILE
     df -h > $DATAFILE
  fi
```

Comment: if [[ -e  ${DATAFILE}]] that solved the problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That should read

```
  if [[ -e "$DATAFILE" ]]
```

Comment: Just to add that when using double brackets the expanded variables are not subject to shell word/field splitting (so the double quotes could be avoided). That, of course, is not the case when using the `[ ... ]` construct.